# Can I repair this sidewall damage or should I get a new tire?

Tags: tires, damage

I hit a curb this morning at pretty low speeds and was thinking that I should be able to repair the damage with rubber cement or something like that but the more I was reading online about sidewall damage the more scared I got and now I am thinking that I will have to buy a new tire. I travel between Cincinnati and Chicago a lot at higher speeds so I just want to make sure that the vehicle will be safe to drive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's generally a bad idea to be getting things like rubber cement involved.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was not able to add pictures from my phone so I had to post it first and then add it from my computer.. the pictures are there now. Thanks!

Comment: No problems - I hit submit on the comment and saw you edited the pics in!

Comment: [Please see this Meta post as to why it is being closed.](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2062/4152)

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it but that doesn't look great - it looks to have taken pretty deep chunk of the sidewall out, and there's what appears to be a deeper split as well.

You really **don't** want to try repairing that with rubber cement - that will have completely different elasticity to the actual rubber of the tire and I could see unpleasant things happening as the sidewall deforms under normal use.

Looking at the pictures (and given the sort of driving you do) I'd be getting a replacement - it looks like it's holding at the moment but I'd be concerned about how it's going to cope with the higher stresses of highway driving and the fact that the structure is already somewhat weakened if a further impact occurs.

It's frustrating to have to pay out for a new tire but at the end of the day the consequences of a high-speed failure could easily be way, way more expensive!